# NVMe + RAID: How to Optimize Lanes?

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, raid, sata, nvme

I have a Samsung 960 Pro, a RAID 1 with 2 Seagate (ST2000dx001) disks and a Blu-ray device (ASUS BW-16D1HT) on Asus H170Pro USB 3.1 with W10/64. I run the 960 with the Bios option “Not RST Controlled” in order to use the Samsung drivers. I observed no difference between the Samsung and the RAID/Intel drivers but the Samsung tools only recognize the 960 with the “Not RST Controlled” option (otherwise no firmware update is possible).

[image]

The 960 is recognized properly by the Samsung Magician tool:

[image]

Among others, the HISO lanes for the H170 are shown here:

[image]
[image]

Currently I have put the RAID on SATA3 and SATA4, Blu-ray on SATA5. SATA 0, 1 and 2 are unused. My graphic card is on pcie16_1 (pcie16_2 is unused).
I want to run the NVMe on most undisturbed lanes (for high performance). How can I configure e.g. the SATA ports and the graphic card best?